# Can't click on checkbox - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple to do list. Its' only options are add, delete and check when done. My trouble lies within the check part.
Checkboxes don't respond to clicks. I've tried other elements and neither them respond to clicks. Here is what is going on:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
   if (checkIfEmpty()) {
    add();
   }
  replaceValue();
});

//delete from list
$("#delete").click(function() {
  $(".list li").toggleClass("active");
  $("#today").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});

//checked
$("#today").on("click", "div", function(e) {
 alert("aaa");
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="list">
  <h3>Today i want to...</h3>
  <button class="btn" id="add">Add</button>
  <button class="btn" id="delete">Delete</button>
  <div class="addToList">
    <input type="text" id="todo" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Add</button>
  </div>
 <ul id="today"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the markup?

Comment: You're using e.stopPropagation. Seeing as your problem is that your checkboxes do not respond to clicks, I bet this is your problem.
Also post your html, so we can actually make attempts to help you instead of just guessing.

Comment: You are stopping the bubbling of the click event here: stopPropagation()

Have you tried removing that and seeing if your click handler works again?

Comment: I've added the html. 
I've tried without the stopPropagation and it didn't change a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the problem is. 
I've used `pointer-events:none` on the li element so it couldn't be deleted. The answer is simply to edit the checkbox class to `pointer-events:auto` and is set to go.
Thank you. It was only a distraction error.